# Why do some sources prefix "BOFURI" to the English title of "Itai no wa Iya nano de Bōgyoryoku ni Kyokufuri Shitai to Omoimasu"?

Tags: funimation, bofuri

The manga and anime are called "痛いのは嫌なので防御力に極振りしたいと思います。" which is translated to "I Don't Want to Get Hurt, so I'll Max Out My Defense." Most English sites about manga and anime list it either in romaji or in the English translation. However Wikipedia lists it as [BOFURI: I Don't Want to Get Hurt, so I'll Max Out My Defense.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOFURI:_I_Don%27t_Want_to_Get_Hurt,_so_I%27ll_Max_Out_My_Defense.) Apparently, they got the title from Funimation.

I have two questions based on that. How did they come up with the prefix, "BOFURI"? What does "BOFURI" mean or stand for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**"*BōFuri*"「防振り」 is the official abbreviation of the title in Japanese.**

It is taken from the Japanese title 「痛いのは嫌なので**防**御力に極**振り**したいと思います。」, which reads "*Itai no wa Iya nano de **Bō**gyoryoku ni Kyoku**furi** Shitai to Omoimasu*".

Related: [Is there a name for the abbreviated (usually three syllable) title?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/is-there-a-name-for-the-abbreviated-usually-three-syllable-title)